# Better way to handle null values in android?

Tags: android, software-quality

Whenever I need to get some data from another activity/intent etc. in android my code essentially has to follow this logic:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

if (intent != null) {
    String intentAction = intent.getAction();

    if (intentAction != null && intentAction.equals("whatever")) {

    // Do some stuff now that we know there are now  null values
    }
}
```

Very verbose and very nested code in my opinion and every time I do this I think to myself "there's gotta be a better way".

> Is there and what would that be?

Comment: What if you check `getIntent().getExtras() != null` ?

Comment: you can use try catch block for null pointer exception

Comment: if you have the same snippet multiple time why not make it static?

Comment: So there is no existing abstraction in java/android to do this?  This was kind of the point of my question.  Sure I can create the helper classes/methods etc. if necessary but I would have thought that something like this would have been solved in deeper level already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine those `if-statements` into one. You won't get an error since the code will 'exit' once the first argument before the `&&` returns `false`.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && intent.getAction().equals("whatever") {

    // Do some stuff now that we know there are now  null values

}
```

Or here's an even shorter way, thanks to a suggestion from @Tomkarho.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();

if (intent != null && "whatever".equals(intent.getAction()) {

    // Do some stuff now that we know there are now  null values

}
```

Comment: What if intent.getAction() is null?

Comment: @Mark  Can't your solution be simplified even more with TextUtils? if (intent != null && TextUtils.equals(intent.getAction(), "whatever"))

Comment: @ Tomkarho You are correct! Smart. I've updated my answer to include yet another way.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally just create some helper methods to clean up the main logic. If this is code that will appear often, you can create a base `Activity` class to hold the `getIntentAction` method, or create a static method in a helper which takes either the `Activity` or its `Intent` as a parameter.

For the String comparison, you can use `TextUtils.equals()`. Alternatively, if you have a String that contains the action name, you can use that as the left hand side of the `equals` method. Just make sure you don't swap the order at a later point.

Some sample code:

```
public static final String WhateverAction = "whatever";

public String getIntentAction()
{
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    return intent == null ? null : intent.getAction();
}
```

Using compare string on left hand side:

```
public void processMyIntent()
{
    String action = getIntentAction();
    if(WhateverAction.equals(action))
    {
        // do something
    }
    else if("thisAlsoWorksAction".equals(action)
    {
        // do something else
    }
    else
    {
        // got null or unexpected value
    }
}
```

Using `TextUtils`:

```
public void processMyIntentTextUtils()
{
    String action = getIntentAction();
    if(TextUtils.equals(action, WhateverAction))
    {
        // do something
    }
    if(TextUtils.equals(action, "anotherAction"))
    {
        // do something else
    }
    else
    {
        // got null or unexpected value
    }
}
```

Using a switch:

```
public void processMyIntentSwitch()
{
    String action = getIntentAction();
    switch(action)
    {
        case WhateverAction:
           //...
           break;

        default:
           // got null or unexpected value
    }
}
```

You could also get away with not having a `getIntentAction` method by just doing this one-liner, though it's a bit wordy:

```
String intentAction = getIntent() != null ? getIntent().getAction() : null;
```

Answer (score -1):

A bad pratice, but shorter (and no if) :

```
try {
  switch (getIntent().getAction()) {
       case "whatever": ...
            ...
         }
} catch e {}
```

Comment: its not a maybe, its a for sure a bad practice to wrap everything in try catch